# Cannot get category.title to show up

Tags: entries, category

```
{% set slug = craft.request.getParam('s') %}

{% if slug | length %}
    {% set category = craft.categories.slug(slug) %}
    {% set faqs = craft.entries.section('faq').order('title').limit(null) %}

    <h3>{{ category.title }}</h3>

    <ul class="no-bullet">
        {% for entry in faqs.relatedTo(category) %}
            {% if entry.level >1 %} 
                <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}  
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <h3> No matching results found </h3>
{% endif %}
```

In the code above, I cannot get `{{ category.title }}` to display. It is empty. If I put `{{ category.slug }}` instead, it shows the correct value. The other items in unordered list are displaying perfectly. I am confused as to why the title is not showing

Comment: If you simplify it to `{% set slug = craft.request.getParam('s') %}{% set category = craft.categories.slug(slug) %}{{ category.title }}` does it work?  Is this a multi-locale setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug(slug) %}
```

to

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug(slug).first() %}
```

Comment: Brad, you nailed it. I still don't understand why you have to explicitly mention `.first()` since there is only one object that is returned.

Comment: Slugs are not unique, ids are, so there is a chance you could have more than one category being returned. Don't quote me on that, but just remember to use first()